# Highcharts, How to show datatable when export PDF and not show pdf when normal

Tags: highcharts

> Help me please,

Highcharts, How to show data table when export pdf and not show data table when normal like this:
[http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/]

> But can show data table when export pdf or print only.

Comment: Please format your question properly and add a more detailed description of your problem. Have a look at this guide for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes in the official demo from FAQ - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#can-i-add-a-data-table-to-the-exported-chart to render table only for export. Take a look and test it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fwtu48s3/

```
events: {
  load() {
    if (this.renderer.forExport) {
      Highcharts.drawTable(this);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: I have something to ask When using as mentioned, it's harder to load PDF or PNG File or sometimes it doesn't load at all.

Comment: What does it mean `it's harder to load PDF or PNG`? And `sometimes it doesn't load at all` - sometimes mean when?